# Create sortable and searchable table with Pandas and Flask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flask, html-table

I created a functions that return a dataframe with pandas.
I'm now looking to display this dataframe with Flask on a webapp.

`

```
@app.route('/', methods=("POST", "GET"))
def html_table():

    return render_template('index.html',  tables=[df.to_html( table_id = 'table', justify = "left", classes='table table-striped', header="true", render_links="True", escape="False")])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`

I modified my HTML to my webapp displays a nice looking table

```
{% block body %}
    <br>
    <h1>Transparency Data for ASBL in Belgium </h1>
    <br>
    <h3>This is a list that automatically verifies if ASBL website contain transparency data and give the date of last publication of financial data.</h3>
    <br>
    <p>We use the CBE public search, Central Balance Sheet Office and web scraping tools to verify check data in real time.</p>
    <br>
    <p>More info on our github: https://github.com/wainaze/Transparencia</p>

    {% for table in tables %}

    {{ table|safe }}
    
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Here's what the table looks like:
[image]

My problem is, I plan to show 500+ lines on this table.
How do I make it sortable and searchable?

I tried with datatable.js
and added some script, in my index.html
`

```
{% block body %}
    <br>
    <h1>Transparency Data for ASBL in Belgium </h1>
    <br>
    <h3>This is a list that automatically verifies if ASBL website contain transparency data and give the date of last publication of financial data.</h3>
    <br>
    <p>We use the CBE public search, Central Balance Sheet Office and web scraping tools to verify check data in real time.</p>
    <br>
    <p>More info on our github: https://github.com/wainaze/Transparencia</p>

    {% for table in tables %}

    {{ table|safe }}
    
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %} 

{% block scripts %}
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#table').DataTable({
        columns: [
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          {searchable: false},
          {orderable: false, searchable: false},
          {orderable: false, searchable: false},
          null],
      });
    });
  </script>
```

`
and on my base.html

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.js"></script>    
            {% block body %}{% endblock %}
          </div>
```

and this is the header of base.html
`

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.css">
```

`

Nothing seems to work and I get the table as above without any changes.
Is there a way to add searchable and sorting to dataframes using .to_html()??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Datatables has a solid search feature.

Either pass the data into the jQuery datatable as JSON in a separate flask API call or use some javascript to grab the datatable and create a jquery datatable around the html table.

```
 <!-- import jq datatables CDN code-->
 <script 
 src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> 
 </script>
 <script 
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"> 
</script>

<table id='my-table'>
 <tr>
  <th>
  <th>
  ....

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  table = $('#my-table').DataTable({
  
  });


});
</script>
```

DataTable is searchable by default. You might want to use this to add rows upon a server request:

```
table.row.add($(newRow)).draw();
```